# Adding Google GTL library to Xcode project

Tags: xcode, libraries

I want to add the Google GTL Objective-C Library to my Xcode project, I just can't work it out and there is next to nothing on the topic that I can find helpful (Google's documentation is awful).

Comment: Congrats on hitting 1,500 rep!  One of the [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges) that you've gained is the ability to create new tags.  Please take care when entering tags from now on.  You just accidentally created a new tag through a typo.

Comment: Please make separate posts for separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n95fl.png

If it won't help you, just grab all needed files from GTL project and manually add all of them to your project.
Something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEt0O.png

Don't forget to disable ARC for all those files.

[How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)